# nginx aliases and dynamic directory names

Tags: nginx, alias

I have spent muy tiempo on this and I can't get a solution.
I need a way to point the same url but with different root directory to the same application. I don't want to use rewrites because the root directoy name has to be processed by the application and rewrite discards it.

```
http://www.host.com/a/ --> /var/www/html/project/
http://www.host.com/b/ --> /var/www/html/project/
http://www.host.com/c/ --> /var/www/html/project/
```

I've managed to configure in nginx an alias directory with a **fixed** name `vdirectory` and make nginx forward the request to fastcgi.

```
location /vdirectory {

      alias /var/www/html/project/;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /vdirectory/index.php;
      location ~ \.php$ {
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
          include fastcgi_params;                       
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
      }
}
```

The above works OK.

Since I don't want to use fixed root directory names but arbitrary ones, this is what I've managed so far:

```
location  ~ ^/(.?)$  {

      alias /var/www/html/project/;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/index.php;
      location ~ \.php$ {
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
          include fastcgi_params;                       
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
      }
}
```

Needless to say, it returns 404. It is a good sign because it means regex has recognized the path, but the request isn't forwarded correctly.

The only difference between the working config and the wrong one is `/vdirectory` vs `~ ^/(.?)$`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`alias` works differently when inside a regular expression `location` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details. You will need to capture the remainder of the URI and append that to the `alias` value. For example:

```
location ~ ^/(?<prefix>[^/]+)/(?<name>.*)$ {
    alias /var/www/html/project/$name;

    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /$prefix/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;                       
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

I avoid using `try_files` and `alias` within the same block due to [long term issues](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Yes. That's what I was looking for. It's so rare to get such a precise  solution. Thanks a Million