# Change root based on location in nginx (homestead)

Tags: nginx, homestead

I have an api that is a separate codebase to the main site.

It has a separate nginx configuration which works when I access it using `api.mydomain.test/api/v1/`.

However I would like to use the site url to access the api code.

My nginx config:

```
server {
  server_name .mydomain.test;

  root "/c/Users/Me/Homestead/site/public"

  index index.html index.html index.php;

  location ~* /api/(v[0-9]+)/ {
    root "/c/Users/Me/Homestead/api/$1/public";
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mydomain.test-error.log debug;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mydomain.test-error.log debug;
  }
}
```

With this configuration going to `mydomain.test` works fine but `mydomain.test/api/v1/` redirects to the `mydomain.test/index.php` file.

The debug log looks like this:

```
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 http cl:-1 max:104857600
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 rewrite phase: 3
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 post rewrite phase: 4
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 generic phase: 5
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 generic phase: 6
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 generic phase: 7
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 access phase: 8
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 access phase: 9
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 access phase: 10
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 access phase: 11
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 post access phase: 12
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 try files phase: 13
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 http script var: "/api/v1/"
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 trying to use file: "/api/v1/" "/c/Users/Me/Homestead/api/v1/public/api/v1/"
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 http script var: "/api/v1/"
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 trying to use dir: "/api/v1/" "/c/Users/Me/Homestead/api/v1/public/api/v1/"
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 http script copy: "/index.php?"
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 trying to use file: "/index.php?" "/c/Users/Me/Homestead/api/v1/public/index.php?"
2018/01/03 12:25:57 [debug] 6669#6669: *10 internal redirect: "/index.php?"
```

Comment: You are testing with `/api/v1` which does not match `location ~* /api/(v[0-9]+)/` - so the `location /` block is used to process the request.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the post now. It does the same thing when I test with /api/v1/

Comment: So your server is looking for content in `/c/Users/Me/Homestead/api/v1/public/api/v1/` and I am guessing that the correct location is `/c/Users/Me/Homestead/api/v1/public/`? Also, your configuration references `index.php` but I cannot see a PHP configuration. Is `/api/v1/` a PHP app?

Comment: Yes, that third attempt in the log is the correct path. The index.php file is in `/c/Users/Me/Homestead/api/v1/public/`.
I've only just now got it working but I'm not sure the way I'm doing it is the best way.
Instead of a new location block I've put an if inside the the `location ~ \.php$ {}` block that checks the url and sets the root accordingly. Though I've read that ifs are a bad idea in nginx configuration.

Comment: The solution is to use `alias` to construct the `$request_filename` and a nested `location` to handle PHP within the alternative root. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567260/nginx-aliases-and-dynamic-directory-names/45568527#45568527) for an example.